# spark-submit: Passing java properties file gives FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a spark job that I am running in `yarn` `cluster` mode. I need to pass my application specific java properties file.
I am doing this java `FileInputStream`.
But I am facing **FileNotFoundException** for /home/aiman/config/my-file.properties

My java properties file is: `/home/aiman/config/my-file.properties`

```
mongo_server=my.mongo.server
mongo_port=1530
mongo_user=mongoadmin
mongo_password=readONLYpass
mongo_db=testdb
```

My `spark-submit` looks like:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --class mongo.MongoRead --jars /home/aiman/ojdbc-7.jar /home/aiman/app/jars/MongoRead-0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar /home/aiman/config/my-file.properties
```

Code snippet:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception
    {       
        if(args.length<1){
            System.out.println("Please provide properties file path");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        System.out.println("Mongo Import Begins...");

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        InputStream in = null;
        try{
            in = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
            prop.load(in);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        /*Reading the properties*/
        String mongoServer = prop.getProperty("mongo_server");
        String mongoPort = prop.getProperty("mongo_port");
        String mongoUser = prop.getProperty("mongo_user");
        ....
        ...

        String mongoAddress = "mongodb://"+mongoUser+":"+mongoPassword+"@"+mongoServer+":"+mongoPort+"/"+mongoDb+"."+tableNm;

        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
            .appName("MongoSparkRecordReader")
            .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", mongoAddress)
            .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", mongoAddress)
            .getOrCreate();

        JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());
        ...
        ..

}
```

Please suggest what is going wrong. Am I reading the properties file in a wrong manner, that it isn't finding the file?

Comment: Your file is not visible from the cluster. Do you have an HDFS place where you could put this file? An alternative is to pass your arguments via the command line (which sucks for the password...).

Comment: Yes I do have HDFS place, but these configuration variables keeps changing, thats why i have it in properties file in local.

Comment: The cluster will look for the file in  /home/aiman/config/my-file.properties and, of course, won't find it. Two options: 1) you create a  /home/aiman/config/ on the cluster and copy the file there everytime you make a modification or 2) you store the information of the file somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the local file via the "--file /home/aiman/config/my-file.properties" spark-submit's argument, which will distribute the file to the containers launched by YARN that will find the "my-file.properties" in their JVM's classpath. You should then be able to read it as a JVM's local resource.

Comment: you are correct @erond. that is the correct way to pass any file.

Answer (score 0):

Running this in `--deploy-mode client` resolves the issue. The Driver is getting launched where the properties file is present. So file is getting read and not getting any Exception.

Comment: IMHO, if the question starts with a "yarn cluster" mode, the answer cannot be "don't use cluster mode, use client".